# Android test whether UI element / View exists

Tags: android, android-widget

If I had a UI element defined by, for example

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/output"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:typeface="monospace" 
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

I could reference it with something like

```
TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
```

However, if the TextView doesn't exist, then I can't even compile the code since there no `R.id.output` is generated and this is caught at compile time.

Is there a way to test whether the element exists without referencing it by the `R.id...`, since that will generate a compile-time error if it does not?

Actually, I believe I would need not only a test to see whether it exists, but also an alternative way of referencing it.

Maybe something like

```
TextView output = null;
if((output = findViewByName("output")) != null)
{
    // Do something with output
}
```

(Of course, the `findViewByName` function doesn't exist.)

Thanks

Comment: You mean the id doesn't exist in the current layout, or isn't defined anywhere in the app?  You can reference any defined id, you'll just get an exception at run time.  I don't know why you'd ever find yourself referencing an id that hasn't been defined anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't exist at all, in any layout.  I think this is actually a side effect of me not using multiple layouts when I should.  You should repost this as an answer because its makes more sense than trying to do what I was thinking about doing.

Comment: But why would you be referencing an id that hasn't been defined?

Comment: For example, if you had code that you knew wouldn't run but didn't want to go through the hassle of commenting it out everywhere.   You want to keep the same java code but present a different layout, one that doesn't include an element that is referenced in a `findViewById()` call.

Comment: Once you build your project I think you will get an error "Id cannot be resolved", something like that because it will depend on the layout passed on setContentView();.

Comment: One may wish to test if view with given id exists when there is 2 versions of the layout for landscape and portrait orientation (one will not contain certain elements) e.g. container for fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Resources class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) method [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to find a resource by name although, as noted in the docs, it is much less efficient than finding by id.